# using "PDFBox" how to identify "Table of contents" page

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I am using apache pdfbox framework to read pdf text content.
I have to get the content from "Table of Content" page (if present in the pdf), should be able to identify the Table of content page through pdfbox api. 
kindly provide your suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

The table of content in a PDF file is not easily identified by any structure you can just pull from the PDF document. You will have to do text extraction and identify the table of content by its properties.

PDF in general doesn't contain content structure such as table of contents, chapters, headers, footers or even paragraphs or lines of text.